# Как прокручивать textbox вниз по мере появления в нем текста?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как прокручивать textbox вниз по мере появления в нем текста?

Comment: Первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу "[textbox scroll to end](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=textbox%20scroll%20to%20end)": [How do I automatically scroll to the bottom of a multiline text box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898307/how-do-i-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-multiline-text-box).

Comment: @DmitryD. благодарю

Comment: @max619: Вы имеете в виду winforms, да?

Comment: @VladD именно winforms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы используете [`TextBox.AppendText(string text)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx), текстбокс будет автоматически прокручиваться к концу добавленного текста. При этом не будет мигания скроллбара, если вы пользуетесь функцией в цикле..

Кроме того, такой подход получается на порядок производительнее, чем конкатенация в свойство `.Text`. Хотя это может зависеть от того, с какой частотой вы вызываете функцию; я тестировал на добавлении данных в цикле без пауз.

---

При этом подходе текст не прокрутится, если добавление происходит *до* того, как текстбокс был показан в UI, или если текстбокс не был видим по какой-либо другой причине (например, он был в другом табе в `TabPanel`). Это может оказаться существенным для вас, если вам нужна автопрокрутка *даже если пользователь не видит текстбокс*.

Один из методов обойти эту проблему — прокрутить скроллбар «вручную» на изменении видимости:

```
textBox.VisibleChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (textBox.Visible)
    {
        textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.TextLength;
        textBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
};
```

---

<sup>Перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14886915/276994) с en.SO</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Правильно использовать метод `textbox.AppendText()`.
Спасибо за ответ DmitryD